# Why does REST API not work on my local MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-installation

I've successfully installed MediaWiki on my laptop. Here is the entry `tease out`.

[image]

As you can see, the link to this entry on my local host is http://192.168.56.1/wiki/index.php/tease_out. Then I want to use REST API to convert this page to html. The corresponding link on the online Wiktionary is https://en.wiktionary.org/w/rest.php/v1/page/tease_out/html. The desired result is

[image]

Then I try http://192.168.56.1/w/rest.php/v1/page/tease_out/html. But it shows

[image]

Could you please elaborate on this issue and how to solve it? Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: You have to use the same URL prefix for `rest.php` that you use for `index.php`.

Comment: @Tgr I tried http://172.30.80.1/wiki/rest.php/tease_out and http://172.30.80.1/wiki/rest.php/tease_out/html, but neither of them worked. Could you please more specific?

Comment: That would be the correct URL. Probably you are applying some rewrite rules via your web server and those extend to index.php only.

Answer (score 0):

You make URLs wrong way.
/w/ in mediawiki examples usually means mediawiki prefix, in your case it is /wiki/

http://192.168.56.1/wiki/rest.php/v1/page/tease_out/html

In URLs that you write in comments you've lost /v1/ in the path.